# Search feature on facebook app

Tags: facebook

I'm building a Facebook canvas app with a search functionality targeted on the app contents. I have read the Facebook developer policy, and they state that in point III-A-3: (a) You must not include advertisements, cross-promote other applications, or provide web search functionality in content distributed through Facebook social channels, and (b) You can only utilize advertising or similar monetization related products or services from companies that appear on this list of Advertising Providers within Apps on Facebook.com.

1. Am I breaking the rule with my custom search module which is limited to my app contents?
2. If I want to monetize this search feature, for example in ranking results, can I implement my custom system or do I need to register to one of the advertising providers?
3. If the answer to the 2 questions above is 'no', what are the best solutions for me?